# Back up administrator appears to be broke?

Tags: password

So I've set up a administrator account for back up incase my main one goes haywire, and well it sort of works. Keep in mind the back up account has no password and anyone can login (I done this because I forget passwords sometimes)

When ever I do something that needs authentication I try and use my back up account but instead of just letting me do it as it has no password, it requires a password

Now I've just tried doing nothing and pressing enter when it requires the password but no, nothing happens either.

Images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUIdG.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: @JohnOrion thank you for that! I feel that that should of been posted as an answer though, since this solved my question. thank you very much though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe that passwords are a safety feature in Linux and are required for the most part. A blank password when trying to authenticate will through an error because blank passwords aren't actually allowed. My suggestions would be to use a real basic password like 1234 or something... basically its a password that isn't a password lol. Also a lot of backup programs need root to function properly so you will usually have to use sudo in a command prompt or gksu on a launcher icon at the beginning of the command to have it go through right and it will ask you for a password.

Due to it possibly needing sudo or gksu ... this may be why its asking for authorization